# How to find distinct records in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, distinct, record

I am inserting below record in MongodB

```
{
    "_class" : "mkcl.os.transformer.PayloadObject",
    "_id" : ObjectId("53763e6fe4b00e612650c18c"),
    "dataMap" : {
        "gpsLocation" : "Latitude: 18.6099243, Longitude:73.7710601,Altitude:0.0",
        "85" : "Prahlad Singh",
        "86" : "25",
        "88" : "16/05/14",
        "92" : "",
        "89" : "Male",
        "91" : "Single",
        "87" : "Pune",
        "90" : "Employement"
    },
    "formId" : NumberLong(22),
    "imageUrls" : {},
    "isDeleted" : false
}
```

there are many records like these. Now, I wants distinct records based on keys 86, 89 and 90.

I am using query db.payloadObject.distinct('dataMap.86') and it is returning distinct records based on value key - 86 . I am not understanding how to fetch value based on these conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Use **aggregate** can return the distinct compound keys, like

```
db.payloadObject.aggregate([{
    $group : {
        _id : {
            86 : "$dataMap.86", 
            89 : "$dataMap.89", 
            90 : "$dataMap.90", 
        }
    }
}]);
```